# How to connect websocket with a mobile application?

Tags: spring, websocket, chat

I need for a mobile application to add websocket to the backend for chat implementation. I found an example https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-websocket-chat-demo, but here the chat is not for a mobile application, I don’t quite understand how to request a chat? should add api, but where?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker


public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
}
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
}
```

I have an `addEndpoint`, should I write api in it?
Since my application does not work with the browser, how to replace `.withSockJS ()`?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(name = "api/chat")

public class ChatController {
@MessageMapping("/chat.sendMessage")
@SendTo("/topic/public")
public ChatMessage sendMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage) {
    return chatMessage;
}

@SendTo("/topic/public")
public ChatMessage addUser(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage,
                           SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
    headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", chatMessage.getSender());
    return chatMessage;
}
```

}

or the data should come through this api?

I do not understand how to receive data in websocket via api from a mobile application in order to save it

Comment: In iOS you can use [this](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream) while for Android you can use [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp)

Comment: not the easiest example))

Comment: Well you didn’t say if you need for iOS, Android, hybrid :)

Comment: i need for hybrid